# windows mobile camera

Tags: windows-mobile

i want to know how to take photo in windowsmobile through c sharp coding and also i want to save it to the database. can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows Mobile 6.5 or earlier, you could use the [CameraCaptureDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.forms.cameracapturedialog.aspx) class:

```
CameraCaptureDialog ccd = new CameraCaptureDialog();
ccd.ShowDialog();
Bitmap capturedImage = new Bitmap(ccd.FileName);
```

Comment: shall you give idea about audio video in c sharp

Comment: Videos are saved as files as well. So you could open the file (using ccd.FileName) with the associated video player app on the device, or maybe use DirectShow.NETCF (http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/directshownetcf/) to play it within your application.